# Alert function is called on all buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert

I'm adding buttons dynamically and setting an event to them:

```
$(document).on("click", ".del-but", remove);
```

In the remove function I have a `confirm` dialog that fires for every button added (3 buttons => 3 times)

```
function remove() {
            var buttonName = $(this).attr("name");
            if (!confirm("Are you  sure you want to remove this " + buttonName + "?\nAll the input will be lost!"))
                return;
            //stuff...
        }
```

The rest of the code (stuff) is not called though, only the dialog. How do I stop the dialog from firing more that once?

```
function addCategory(btn) {            
            var $addCategory = "<fieldset>";
            $addCategory += "<legend>Category " + createRemoveButton("category") + "</legend>";
            $addCategory += '@Html.Label("Name")';
            $addCategory += '@Html.TextBox("name")';
            $addCategory += "<br />";
            $addCategory += addCategoryButton;
            $addCategory += addChartButton;
            $addCategory += "</fieldset>";            
            $(btn).parent().append($addCategory);
            $(document).one("click", ".del-but", remove);
            $(btn).siblings(".add-chart-but").remove();
        }

function createRemoveButton(name) {
            return "<button class=\"del-but\" type=\"button\" name =\"" + name + "\">Remove</button>";
        }
```

Comment: 3 alerts are fired by 3 buttons!

Comment: @jeekonline but I only press 1 at a time and still getting 3 alerts

Comment: $(".del-but").click( function(){ remove(); })

Comment: your 3 button class is .del-but?

Comment: `del-but` is the class for the remove button

Comment: seems fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4epdp0n4/1/

Comment: where is the code placed?

Comment: I miss the NARQ closing reason.

Comment: show your html also, as what @ArunPJohny fiddle did not seem to hit the same issue like what you had

Comment: does addCategory(btn) method called each time when you adding buttons?

Comment: @ArunPJohny thanks the problem was that I was setting the click event every time I added the button.

Comment: `$(document).one("click", ".del-but", remove);` should be outside the `addCategory()`

Answer (score 0):

To delete the event from the clicked button, you can simply delete the class `del-but` from it like this :

```
function remove() {
  // stuffs
  $(this).removeClass('del-but');
}
```

If you are using this class for CSS or other thing, use an other class only for binding and deleting the event. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

what does this do

```
$(document).one("click", ".del-but", remove);
```

in the function addCategory, if you had defined event with

```
$(document).on("click", ".del-but", remove);
```

just remove the previous line.

Comment: one doesn't solve the problem and it also removed the event entirely form the other buttons

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you create event for each create button function called in line;

```
$(document).one("click", ".del-but", remove);
```

You call one time that is enough for this function;

```
$(document).on("click", ".del-but", remove);
```

You can look that in [here](http://jsfiddle.net/120bg3pj/4/)